# "so be it" vs "be it so"

Tags: difference, subjunctives

[so be it - thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/so+be+it):
**(1a)** *If you really want to throw your career away because of some idealistic principle, **so be it***.
**(2a)** *Mary has decided that this is what she wants. **So be it***.

[be it so - thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Be+it+so):
be it so - a phrase of supposition, equivalent to suppose it to be so; or of permission, signifying let it be so.

Do "so be it" and "be so it" mean the same?
If not, then what's the difference between them?

---

my variants:

**(1b)** *If you really want to throw your career away because of some idealistic principle, **be it so***.
Do (1a) and (1b) mean the same?
If not, then what's the difference between them?

**(2b)** *Mary has decided that this is what she wants. **Be it so***.
Do (2a) and (2b) mean the same?
If not, then what's the difference between them?

Comment: The difference is that _plenty of people say_ 'so be it' (it's a fixed phrase) and _nobody says_ 'be it so'.

Comment: 'Be it so' is like Yoda meets Blackadder. "That it be" "'Yes it is', not 'that it be', I'm not a tourist!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two phrases are not equivalent.

"So be it" is an abdication of responsibility, or an acknowledgment of the situation. In sentence 1a it means something like "If you really want to throw your career away because of some idealistic principle, I guess that's how it will be".

"Be it so" is nearly the opposite. It is an order or a grant of permission. Sentence 1b means "If you really want to throw your career away because of some idealistic principle, I order (or allow) it to be so".

Note that this usage of "be it so" is the second definition given. The first definition is used to conjoin sentences. For example, "Mary has decided that this is what she wants. Be it so, I wash my hands of it".

Note also that "be it so" is not used in modern idiomatic English. It feels very old fashioned.

Comment: Sorry for the question but for the ELL forum it's very important: Are you a native English speaker? This would be more clear to what extent you can be trusted in such questions like this one. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am a native English speaker. I'm primarily familiar with "be it so" from sources such as Shakespeare. It is not used in modern writing.